# Hide div when input is clicked

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I wrote a line where if an input is clicked it hides a div. The div is a static utility nav bar that caused an issue with Android's native keyboard. here is the code but the issue is it runs 9 sometimes 10 times and my back end developer says it will be a performance issue. What can i do to prevent this from happening? I am new to javaScript and jQuery so getting this far is good for me.

```
    function utilityNav() {
  if($(window).width() < 891) {
  //Utility Mobile Nav background-color
  var div = $('.navbar-static-bottom').show();
  $('input').focus(function() {
     $('.navbar-static-bottom').fadeOut();
     $("."+$(this).attr('input')).fadeIn();
  });

  $('input').blur(function() {
     $('.navbar-static-bottom').fadeIn();
  });
  }
}
utilityNav();
$(window).on('resize', utilityNav);
$('input').blur(utilityNav);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      //Setup
  function utilityNav() {
    if($(window).width() < 891) {
      //Utility Mobile Nav background-color
      $('.navbar-static-bottom').show();
    }
  }
  function setupUtil(){
    $('body').on('focus', 'input', debounce(function(e) {
      if($(e.currentTarget).is(':focus')) {
        $('.navbar-static-bottom').fadeOut();
      }
    }, 100));

    $('body').on('blur', 'input', debounce(function(e) {
      if(!$(e.currentTarget).is(':focus')) {
        $('.navbar-static-bottom').fadeIn();
      }
    }, 100));
  }

  setupUtil();
  $(window).on('resize', utilityNav);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is running so many times is because if the window resizes you are adding an event ever time.

As you resize the window, the event will fire multiple times. Every time the window resizes you are adding a new event.

you need to do this.

```
//SETUP

function utilityNav() {
  if($(window).width() < 891) {
  //Utility Mobile Nav background-color
  $('.navbar-static-bottom').show();
}

function Setup(){
  $('input').focus(function() {
     $('.navbar-static-bottom').fadeOut();
     $("."+$(this).attr('input')).fadeIn();
  });

  $('input').blur(function() {
     $('.navbar-static-bottom').fadeIn();
     utilityNav();
  });
  }
}


utilityNav();
$(window).on('resize', utilityNav);
```

I have not tested this but structurally this is what you need to do.
There are still better improvements you need to add. 
Instead of placing the event on the input tag you should use delegates. You can read up on this.

For example if you were to add a new input box to the page afterwards. This would not work.

Comment: Ok so your code did not work but i think it lead me to the correct answer so i really really appreciate your time and energy with helping me.

Comment: okay it would be wise to (a) explain the correct solution, (b) allow me to edit my answer and (c) upvote my result so other can see the solution as well and be presented. It's just good manners ;)

Comment: Lpc_dark I apologize I am not trying to be inconsiderate. I will get to this hopefully today. My project is in final prep for launch and have to focus at this time for the release. To explain briefly I targeted the body for inputs and the focus event then hide the utility bar when it was focus i used debounce and a delay timer to ensure the utility nav stayed hidden and did not fade in fade out quickly if you clicked the "X" to clear input. I will get better as i keep learning I really appreciate the help and direction on this. Thank you again!)